# symfony : how to use phpunit to test the response of each page

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, web-crawler

I am starting to get interested in unit tests and I understood we do almost what we wanted.

How can I test a page's response (make sure it returns a 200 code) ? I get lost in all the many options. Does someone have a simple example ?

I know how to generate a list of all my pages, now I want to test each of them and make sure the response is not a 500.

EDIT:

So I have installed PhpUnit with composer and I have tried using an example from symfony cookbook:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider urlProvider
     * @param $url
     */
    public function testPageIsSuccessful($url)
    {
        $client = self::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', $url);

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    }

    public function urlProvider()
    {
        return array(
            array('/'),
        );
    }
}
```

Now I want to run this tests i.e. call testPageIsSuccessful on every element of the provided array, with phpUnit. phpunit.bat is located in my symfony/bin folder.

So trying to launch `phpunit.bat` gets me a list of options. Now trying to launch `phunit ../src/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest` gets me the following error :

```
Cannot run program "phunit" (in directory "D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev"): CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of the code you have so we can see what you're attempting to do?

Comment: Are you looking to do unit tests or functional ones? Broadly the difference is that unit tests are simple, quick items of work outside of the browser environment, and functional tests will actually go through HTTP to see if it works in that environment. Projects will often have both types of test. Since you're referring to getting a 200 response code, I wonder if you really are wanting to do functional/browser tests, e.g. with Selenium or PhantomJS.

Comment: From my understanding it's more about functional tests. Please have a loot at my edit. I'm not sure how I can launch the tests now, in addition of is the test I wrote actualluy meant to perform what I explained I was looking for.

Comment: Try to use any web crawler. It will show you your page's response code.

Comment: @Oleg, would you have a simple example of a crawler looping through all my symfony2 pages ?

Comment: @Sébastien Vassaux, e.g. Xenu.

Comment: So I've tested it and a crawler is not really the solution for me, not clean enough. I'd like to loop through my routes, not test every possible link (close to the infinite). I'll deep into phpunit...

Comment: You wrote `phunit`, a `p` is missing.

Comment: You can do this with `$this->kernel->getContainer()->get('router')->getCollection()->all();` but it smells. What exactly are you testing here? If there are no routes your test will still succeed. If you really want to test every action just create a separate test for each. You can then make sure you are requesting every URL with proper params, simulate exceptions and so on. Otherwise you are writing tests for the sole purpose of writing tests. I don't think it is what you want.